# MemoryError when trying to run python programm

Tags: python, algorithm, dataframe, data-science

Hello python's programmers , i'm new at programming here is the part of code, i want to convert seqentiel txt file to data frame , But it stop running because of this line
in

```
    Citations = Citations.join(text_data[i][1:].join(", "))
```

it stops running
here is the error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ea77e42ab01f> in <module>()
     66     ###Traitement List Citation et Nbre Citation
     67   while (text_data[i].find('%') != -1):
---> 68     Citations = Citations.join(text_data[i][1:].join(", "))
     69     CitationsCount = CitationsCount + 1
     70     i = i + 1

MemoryError:
```

The part of code is below

```
while i != len(text_data):

  if (text_data[i].find('*') != -1) : 
    PaperTitle.append(text_data[i][1:])
    Citations = ""
    CitationsCount = 0
    #print("\n PaperTitle :",text_data[i][1:])
    i=i+1

  if (text_data[i].find('@') != -1) :
    Authors.append(text_data[i][1:])
    print("Authors :", text_data[i][1:]) 
    i = i+1
    NbrAuthors.append(0)
    #print("NbrAuthors:", text_data[i][1:])
  
  if (text_data[i].find('t') != -1) :
    Year.append(text_data[i][1:])
    #print("Year : ",text_data[i][1:])
    i=i+1
    
  if (text_data[i].find('c') != -1) :
    PublicationVenue.append(text_data[i][1:])
    #print("PublicationVenue :" ,text_data[i][1:])
    i=i+1

  if (text_data[i].find("index") != -1):
    IdPaper.append(text_data[i][5:])
    #print("IdPaper : ", text_data[i][5:])
    i=i+1

    
    ###Traitement List Citation et Nbre Citation
  while (text_data[i].find('%') != -1): 
    Citations = Citations.join(text_data[i][1:].join(", "))
    CitationsCount = CitationsCount + 1
    i = i + 1
    
  if (text_data[i].find('!')!= -1):
    ListCitations.append(Citations)
    #print("Citations : ",Citations)
    NbrCitations.append(CitationsCount)
    #print("Nbre Citation :",NbrCitations)
    Abstract.append(text_data[i][1:])
    #print("Abstract",text_data[i][1:])
    i=i+1


data = {'PaperTitle': PaperTitle, 
        'Authors': Authors, 
        'NbrAuthors': NbrAuthors, 
        'Year' : Year,
        'PublicationVenue' : PublicationVenue,
        'IdPaper' : IdPaper,
        'ListCitations' : ListCitations,
        'NbrCitations' : NbrCitations,
        'Abstract' : Abstract
        }
```

How can i optimaze my code so i won't get this error

Answer (score 0):

A memory error means that your program has run out of memory. This means that your program somehow creates too many objects. In your example, you have to look for parts of your algorithm that could be consuming a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

which os are you using ? windows, mac,linux ??

if you are on a windows and you have a 32bit intel processor, this error can occur, when you computer is out of memory, and to solve this error, you need more memory,

for example, if all of your files consume 3 GB of data, you must ATLEAST have 5 GB of space  in that particular folder or drive.

it's very rare that you get memory errors while using a 64 bit intel processor in windows
,
but even if you get this error, then you might want to install python 64bit.

and even after this, the problem is not solved, then compress the file/folder, to save atleast 20 MB of disk space.

and even after trying this, the prolem is not solved, then email me,
my email is tlevi16@outlook.com